# User can do to the same level twice

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have been working for some time on the game. It is not too difficult and there are levels.

Every time a user passes level, he is getting a point.
What happens is that a user can do the same level several times and take on some of the points he wants, how do I fix it? I do not get along.

Comment: Please have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It helps you to create a good question.

Comment: @StefanFreitag Im really sorry I tried but I cant explain it right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not wrong, you are asking how make sure that a user doesn't get a point again for the stage he have also crossed/solved.

Well, there is this simple idea. For each stage keep a TAG (unique name) and if the user have successfully crossed the stage, give him a point and set the TAG value to 1 or TRUE, in shared-preferences.
So, if the user plays again the same level, you check the TAG and if and only if the TAG is unset you give him score/point, otherwise you don't give the score/point.

**This is how you store  pair in Shared Preferences:**

```
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("MY_PREF_FILE_NAME", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putInt("LEVEL-1", "1"); //1 means cleared level
    editor.commit();
```

**Let me give you sample(Note make changes as per your need)**

```
    int score = 0; 
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MY_PREF_FILE_NAME", MODE_PRIVATE); 
    int alreadyWon = prefs.getInt("LEVEL-1", -1); // This function means; give me the value of LEVEL-1 if exits, else return -1
    if(alreadyWon == 1){
        // you have already given the score
        //TODO -> what to do next
    }
    else{
        //you have not got the score before for this level, so give score of 1
        score = score + 1;
        //and now set the score of this level in shared preferences
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("MY_PREF_FILE_NAME", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putInt("LEVEL-1", "1"); //1 means cleared level
        editor.commit();
    }
```

Comment: That's it!! can you help me write that code? That's what I failed

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> completedLevels = new ArrayList<String>();

public void onLevelComplete(String levelName) {
    if (!completedLevels.contains(levelName)) {
        completedLevels.add(levelName);
        score += 1
    }
}
```